# write 3d video from kinect to file

Tags: 3d, format, storage, kinect

I am able to get 3d point cloud from kinect.
My questions are, 
 1. how to store this 3d video to disk?
 2. Is there a standard format?
 3. How to view this data from stored file?

I am not interested in converting to movie etc, as I need the true 3d data from disk.
Appreciate any help/information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have personally used the openframeworks addon ofxKinect to record and playback the 3D data from the kinect. The ofxKinectRecorder class in this addon can be used to store the raw data stream from the kinect in a generic .dat format, which you can reload and playback using another class in the addon, ofxKinectPlayer.

You can find the addon here: https://github.com/ofTheo/ofxKinect

The example file has the basics of the kinect recorder/player implemented.